# Jekyll: simplest possible rakefile to create new post

Tags: ruby, rake, jekyll

I just started using jekyll (I am new to `ruby`) and am trying to create a rakefile to automate the creation of posts.

I want to type something like: `rake post title="x"` and have it create a post with that title and today's date.

Right now I am looking at the `rakefile` from `jekyll bootstrap` but it seems like overkill for what I want.

I cut it down to:

```
require 'rake'
require 'yaml'

SOURCE = "."
CONFIG = {
  'posts' => File.join(SOURCE, "_posts"),
  'post_ext' => "md",
}

# Usage: rake post title="A Title"
desc "Begin a new post in #{CONFIG['posts']}"
task :post do
  abort("rake aborted: '#{CONFIG['posts']}' directory not found.") unless FileTest.directory?(CONFIG['posts'])
  title = ENV["title"] || "new-post"
  slug = title.downcase.strip.gsub(' ', '-').gsub(/[^\w-]/, '')
  filename = File.join(CONFIG['posts'], "#{Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}-#{slug}.#{CONFIG['post_ext']}")
  if File.exist?(filename)
    abort("rake aborted!") if ask("#{filename} already exists. Do you want to overwrite?", ['y', 'n']) == 'n'
  end

  puts "Creating new post: #{filename}"
  open(filename, 'w') do |post|
    post.puts "---"
    post.puts "layout: post"
    post.puts "title: \"#{title.gsub(/-/,' ')}\""
    post.puts "category: "
    post.puts "tags: []"
    post.puts "---"
  end
end # task :post
```

But maybe there is a cleaner way to go about this.

**Question**: can this be simplified further or is there a better way to do what I am trying to do?

Comment: Have you checked out http://octopress.org/ ? It may provide some of the functionality that you're looking for.

Comment: @nicksuch thanks, will check it out. Might be better than messing around with `rakefiles`

Comment: Reporting back. Turns out Octopress was perfect for me. Thanks again. Going to forget about `rakefiles` for now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you (or anyone) is still interested, a quite minimal rakefile could be:

```
require 'time'

desc 'create a new draft post'
task :post do
    title = ENV['TITLE']
    slug = "#{Date.today}-#{title.downcase.gsub(/[^\w]+/, '-')}"

    file = File.join(
        File.dirname(__FILE__),
        '_posts',
        slug + '.markdown'
    )

    File.open(file, "w") do |f|
        f << <<-EOS.gsub(/^     /, '')
        ---
        layout: post
        title: #{title}
        published: false
        categories:
        ---

        EOS
    end

    system ("#{ENV['EDITOR']} #{file}")
end
```

Taken from [here](http://arjanvandergaag.nl/blog/creating-new-jekyll-posts.html).

Comment: I prefer modifying this code with the approach used here: https://github.com/gummesson/jekyll-rake-boilerplate. The post creation logic is clearly separated from the post template by pointing to a template file through config.yaml.

Comment: I'd like add date into post too: '''date:   #{Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')}'''

Answer (score 7):

Well, you could just use the [Jekyll Compose Plugin](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-compose). It works pretty well.

Run

```
bundle init
```

add

```
gem 'jekyll-compose', group: [:jekyll_plugins]
```

to your Gemfile.

Run

```
bundle
```

and, finally, run the plugin commands to manage your pages and posts.